# Pipeline step having trouble resolving a file path

Tags: jenkins, protractor, jenkins-pipeline

I am having trouble getting a shell command to complete in a stage I have defined:

```
stages {
    stage('E2E Tests') {
        steps {
            node('Protractor') {
                checkout scm
                sh '''
                    npm install
                    sh 'protractor test/protractor.conf.js --params.underTestUrl http://192.168.132.30:8091'
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The shell command issues a protractor call which takes a config file argument, but this file fails to be found when protractor tries to retrieve it.

If I take a look at the workspace directory for where the repo is checked out to from the `checkout scm` step I can see the test directory is present with the config file present the `sh` step is referencing.

So I'm unsure why the file cannot be found.

I thought about trying to verify the files that can be seen around the time the protractor command is being issued.

So something like:

```
stages {
    stage('E2E Tests') {
        steps {
            node('Protractor') {
                checkout scm
                def files = findFiles(glob: 'test/**/*.conf.js')
                sh '''
                    npm install
                    sh 'protractor test/protractor.conf.js --params.underTestUrl http://192.168.132.30:8091'
                '''
                echo """${files[0].name} ${files[0].path} ${files[0].directory} ${files[0].length} ${files[0].lastModified}"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work, I dont think findFiles can be used inside a step?

Can anyone offer any suggestions about what may be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a `sh` inside of a `sh`?

Comment: I realised that shortly after post the question, I feel dumb now!

Answer (score 0):

to do the debugging you were attempting (to see if the file is actually there)  you could wrap the findFiles in a script (making sure your echo is before the step that fails) or use a basic find in an "sh" step like this:

```
stages {
  stage('E2E Tests') {
    steps {
      node('Protractor') {
        checkout scm

        // you could use the unix find command instead of groovy's findFiles
        sh 'find test -name *.conf.js'

        // if you're using a non-dsl-step (like findFiles), you must wrap it in a script
        script {
          def files = findFiles(glob: 'test/**/*.conf.js')
          echo """${files[0].name} ${files[0].path} ${files[0].directory} ${files[0].length} ${files[0].lastModified}"""
          sh '''
            npm install
            sh 'protractor test/protractor.conf.js --params.underTestUrl http://192.168.132.30:8091'
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, turns out this was me being stupid - I had an sh within an sh!

Comment: luckily i copied and pasted that into my answer. :D